# How can I downgrade GCC to version 6 on 20.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, gcc

How can I downgrade GCC to version 6 on 20.04?

I need GCC6 to compile CUDA9 files.

Trying

`apt install gcc-6` is giving me this error:

```
Package gcc-6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gcc-6' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: I'm looking for GCC 6 not g++6, do you happen to  know the universe repo url for this package? Thanks

Comment: @KnudLarsen Universe and Multiverse repos are already there. How would I install GCC6 in 20.04?

Comment: I added this line: `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) bionic main universe` to /etc/apt/sources.list. And typed `apt install g++-6` and got the error: `Package 'g++-6' has no installation candidate`.

Comment: I also modified the line and removed this part `$(lsb_release -sc)` so that after the word ubuntu there is a space and bionic. Saved it and tried to install but got the same error.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 : I added `deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe`  and did `sudo apt update && sudo apt install g++-6` : All OK. gcc-6, g++-6 was installed.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks it worked. If you type an answer with this solution, I'll select it as the answer for this question.

Comment: After it was installed, I changed the default gcc to version 6, using `update-alternatives --config gcc` and I checked if the change has taken place system wide with `gcc --version` and it shows it is 6 but when I tried to compile Cuda 9 sample files and it again showed me the error GCC version is unsupported and requires GCC 6. Are there any other place where I have to change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Ubuntu 20.04, gcc-6

Please do not remove / change the system gcc : You can have as many gcc versions as you want, installed at the same time.
Add (temporarily) a line to /etc/apt/sources.list :

`apt [url] bionic main universe`, and do

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install g++-6
```

My test : {gcc-6, g++-6} was installed OK.

Using extra compilers, examples : `export CC=gcc-6 CXX=g++-6 && ./configure` and `make CC=gcc-6 CXX=g++-6`

Other (non PIE) extra compilers for Ubuntu https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing

Comment: in your answer you didn't mention the link you wrote to add to the sources file.

Comment: I meant this URL: `deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe`

Comment: The local mirror is my example. You can use any other valid mirror / URL.

Comment: But you should mentioned because when I used `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` I got errors. I was able later when you mentioned that because gcc-6 and g++-6 was available on your local server. Those are not available on global mirrors for bionic.

Comment: gcc-6, g++-6 etc. seems to be present at http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu → universe/g/gcc-6 → http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-6/ .... so quite puzzling why you cannot fetch it.

Comment: I literally told you I added  `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` to sources file and updated and tried to install and got the error I showed you in my question.